# Using trial division in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$, factor $x^6+x^4+x$ into a product of irreducible polynomials.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know how to normally factor this, but I am hazy on the idea of irreducible polynomials. I know that $x^6+x^4+x=x(x^5+x^3+1)$ but I am not sure how to tell if the second factor is irreducible, or if I need to further factorize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If there is an irreducible factor of $x^5+x^3+1$, there is an irreducible factor of degree $\le 2$. The irreducible polynomials of degree $1$ are $x$ and $x+1$, and they obviously don't work (no roots). The only irreducible of degree $2$ is $x^2+x+1$. Try it.

Comment: Thank you for that hint, how do you know that it is of degree less than or equal to two though?

Comment: If the degree $5$ polynomial splits as $p(x)q(x)$ where $p$ and $q$ are not constant, and degree of $p$ is $\le$ degree of $q$, then $p$ has degree $1$ and $q$ has degree $4$, or $p$ has degree $2$ and $q$ has degree $3$.

Comment: Oh, okay so another problem similar to this I have is x^8+x^7+x^6+x^4+1, so if I am applying what you said correctly, does that mean that one of the factors has a degree of < or = to 7? And with that information, I have to use trial and error of all of the irreducible polynomials of degree < or = 7 in Z/2Z. Correct?

Comment: Also, when I tried dividing by x^2+x+1, I got x^3-x^2+x remainder (-x+1)....So does that mean that the form I had it in in my question has factors that are both irreducible

Comment: Yes, I also computed and got the same remainder. (Well, I called it $x+1$, which is the same thing. Love fields of characteristic $2$, since it is impossible to make a sign error!) The conclusion is that the factor $x^5+x^3+1$ is irreducible.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. Is there a way to tell that a polynomial is in an irreducible form just by looking at it?

Comment: Not in general, unfortunately.